# Laravel pivot table between two schemas

Tags: php, laravel, database, pivot, sharding

I have two MySQL schemas like this:

Database A containing "categories"
Database B containing "customers"

Now, I need to create a pivot relationship between them, so "category_customer" is inserted into Database B. Can I use the classic pivot form to create the relationship? Then add the foreign key that points to Database A?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes this would be possible, in theory you just have to point both models to the correct database driver and eloquent should do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the pivot table "category_customer" in Database B and add the foreign key that points to the "categories" table in Database A:

```
Schema::create('category_customer', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('databaseA.categories');
    $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('databaseB.customers');
});
```

in the Model you can use the belongsToMany method to define the relationship.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'databaseB.category_customer', 'category_id', 'customer_id');
    }
}

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'databaseB.category_customer', 'customer_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```